# CSS Floating Div Element Issue

Tags: css, html, floating

I have coded a little bit of my website, but I'm noticing I have to make stupidly big adjustments to get things to fit nicely together, I believe its because I have 2 floating elements and the float is carrying onto the next set of divs even though there not nested!!

Does anyone know why this is happening to make things simpler I have made it live so far what I have done in this example you will notice (if your monitor is wide enough) that the text 
"Do you have special requirements?" has the "Do" about half way up the page?

I think the problem lies around the div tags "bannerleft" and "bannerright" after that I think the float carrys on and breaks everything? I could be wrong

Here is the live example [Here](http://jordan.xronn.co.uk/)

Comment: Please do not ask users to reverse-engineer external sites. Post the relevant code (html+css) as part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't cleared your floats (the two divs in question) .. simply add

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

after the bannerright/bannerleft divs to clear the floats and allow the rest of your document to respect those floated elements .. when you float something you take it out of the "flow"

[Read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clear) this link from MDN for more info on clearing floats ..

P.S. (There are many different ways to clear floats, some cleaner ways than the method I provided, I just did it for simplicity)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I wasn't sure if you wanted me to add it after each div or after that section but either way I couldn't get it to work. I will do some reading and look into this deeper maybe the issue isn't just that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.clearfix {
clear: both;
}
```

On the last floated element

Comment: Hi, thanks unfortunately  this broke everything :( thanks though I will keep searching

Comment: Lol, it is the same exact thing Perfect Dark suggested except mine is a css rule that is separated from HTML (like it should be) and his is a css rule inside the HTML.  The rule is the exact same thing - clear:both.  Just so you know, to apply this rule you would have to do the following: <div class="clearfix"></div>  I assumed you knew that but perhaps I should have included that.

Comment: If you knew that, then how did the same css style solve your problems and break everything?

Answer (score 0):

Nat, this is not happening in firefox. Try placing a either a max or min width on your body tag, maybe 980px and also include overflow: hidden on the body tag.